# how to give a sub child for other sub child in angular two

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to create a sub child for other sub child. I want the structure of my project to be in this form

1. approute
   logincomponent
   notfoundcomponent
   additionalroutingmodule (loaded using lazy routing)
2. additional routing module
    -othersubmodule(loaded using lazy loading)
    -other2submodule(loaded using lazy loading)
   here is the code for the module

   ```
   export const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/additional.module#AdditionalModule' },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: 'change-password', component: ChangePasswordComponent },
   { path: 'not-allowed', component: NotAllowedComponent },
   { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }/**/

   ];
   ```

   for additional module

   ```
       export const routes: Routes = [
       {
           path: '', component: AppHomeComponent, children:
           [
               { path: 'party', loadChildren: 'app/party/party.module#PartyModule' },
               { path: 'product', loadChildren: 'app/product/product.module#ProductModule' },
               { path: 'order', loadChildren: 'app/order/order.module#OrderModule' },
               { path: 'accounting', loadChildren: 'app/accounting/accounting.module#AccountingModule' }
           ]
       }
   ];
   ```

so the error is while routing when accessing the sub child of the additonalroutingmodule it won't get the path it will displayed in parenthesis 
e.g new/new-list(old/old-list)

Comment: found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

giving a parent path name for the appmodule will solve the problem